# Using datepickers in my React Project - Which is the best datepicker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am not sure if this is the best place to ask this type of question.

I am currently developing a React website.

My project requires the use of date input fields.

I want to implement a user-friendly method of inputting a date.

From what I can tell I have four options:

1. A native HTML input field with the type date
2. A jQuery UI datepicker
3. A react datepicker imported from a pre-made library
4. Build my own

One crucial thing that I would like to have is mobile compatibility. E.g. if the user is browsing my website on mobile device instead of showing them a full size date picker widget I would like to use the mobile devices native means for inputting the date e.g. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker and the Android equivalent.

So my question here is, what would the best approach be here?

Comment: Unless you need some special feature or old  browser support like IE11 support I would favour native date picker and let the device load the most suitable one for the hardware and locale

Answer (score 1):

the important thing i wanted to say that you should never use jquery with react because it violates the virtual dom and u absolutely don't need it in your case

i won't spent time building my own datepicker since it is not necessity in your case  since your are using the datepicker among other data to create the website ... you can build your own datepicker if you need some customization that doesn't exist currently on the native html input field or in any library available ... or you have spare time to spend

so i would go for " react a pre-made library"

in my project i used

> https://github.com/arqex/react-datetime

which was quite simple to use ... i hope i helped you a bit